# Any way to convert CAD files to 3d mesh file formats (gltf, FBX, etc) in scripted manner?

Tags: 3d, autocad, gltf, cad

I have a large amount of CATIA CAD files (.CATProduct, .CATPart) that I want to convert to a 3D mesh file format (preferably gLTF, but STL/OBJ/FBX may be okay as well). Are there any programs or binaries that let me do this in a scripted manner on Linux? I tried Unreal's Datasmith but it seems to only export to FBX and requires the entire studio running for any scripts to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Proprietary CAD formats are mostly closed (CATIAv5 for example), and converting them requires specific commercial libraries. There is a few competitors on the market for this, I used to work for one of them. This is working well in practice.